# Use dust.js in common with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, dust.js

How can I use vue.js with the dust template engine? Both are using {{}} as placeholders, are there any options to say dust: Hey, this part is especially for vue?

I got no idea since I haven't had found anything in the documentations.

Answer (score 5):

https://vuejs.org/api/#delimiters

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['!v', 'v!']
```

You can set the delimiters for Vue to whatever you'd like to avoid conflict.  Also see `Vue.config.unsafeDelimiters` - https://vuejs.org/api/#unsafeDelimiters

Comment: Thank you a lot! Delimiters was the keyword I gone in stuck with... :D

Answer (score 3):

The converse answer for Dust is that you can wrap a block in `` {` `` tags to tell Dust not to parse that block.

```
context = { "dust": "DUST!", "vue": "error" }

{dust} says {` hello {vue}! `}
```

will render to

```
DUST! says hello {vue}!
```

Comment: Haha it's fun to see a question with two comingled answers where two libraries interact :D